# thick shadow with no blur on UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, shadow

I am trying to add a thick shadow to a UILabel, without any blur. In photoshop I would use the "Spread" option to make the shadow look like this. It's for a comic book themed UI in an app I am developing. I cannot use images as the text is dynamic and different for each user.

Here is what I am after (on the left) and here is as far as I have gotten so far with CGShadowWithColor (on the right):

[image]

Anyone know how I can achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack to try would be to have several black UILabels below the white one, each offset slightly.